# Is this correct "with my head faced up" "with my face faced up"

Tags: prepositional-phrases

I don't know if this expression is correct.

I looked up at the sky, with my face faced up.

I looked up at the sky, with my head faced up.

1. with my face faced up
2. with my head faced up

Comment: 'I turned my face to the sky'. (It would be difficult to look at the sky without turning your face upwards, but if you need to stress the fact, use _face_, not _head_.)

Comment: Thanks for answer. You mean "I looked up at the sky, with my face faced up" is also possible?

Comment: No. The correct expression is _facing up[wards]_, but it doesn't sound good to use the noun _face_ and the verb _face_ consecutively. I suggest '_turned_ or _tilted_ up'.

Comment: Just one more. Can I say "I close my eyes and cup my hands, palm facing up" or "I close my eyes and cup my hands, palm being up" or "I close my eyes and cup my hands, palm up"

Comment: You have already asked about this on ELU. My take on it is that cupped hands have their palms up by definition; you cup your hands in order to receive something, and we normally picture a cup as being the right way up.

Comment: Ok and Thx. Btw, do you think I can use "I close my eyes and cup my hands, palm facing up."?

Comment: You obviously didn't understand my last comment. In my opinion _I cup my hands_ is sufficient.

Comment: I understood but it was in the research paper as "palm face up" and I congugate it as just "facing" instead of "face" to properly use English.

Comment: OK, I looked back at the passage you quoted, which refers to _one_ hand 'palm face up'. Oxford Dictionaries defines _face up_ as _with the face or surface turned upwards to view_. Obviously for both hands it's _palms_. I think we should end this conversation  now, as it's a digression from your original question.